# WSO2 ESB 4.9.0 ignore declared axis2 bind-address

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

The problem is the following:

1)      We have a machine with multiple interfaces (each one with its own IP), and we want to bind one specific IP to the ESB proxy services (for security reasons).

2)      We are  following WSO2 documentation in order to set up host name and ports: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Setting+Up+Host+Names+and+Ports

3)      We have changed the axis2.xml configuration file, editing the 2 parameters “bind-address” and “WSDLEPRPrefix” with the chosen IP:

```
<transportReceiver name="http" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.HttpCoreNIOListener">
    <parameter name="port" locked="false">8280</parameter>
    <parameter name="bind-address" locked="false">10.10.16.15</parameter>
    <parameter name="WSDLEPRPrefix" locked="false">http://10.10.16.15:8280</parameter>
</transportReceiver>
```

4)      When we start the ESB the log outputs the following lines:

```
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 28.087] INFO - PassThroughHttpSSLListener Starting Pass-through HTTPS Listener ...
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 28.093] INFO - PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager Pass-through HTTPS Listener started on 0.0.0.0:8243
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 28.093] INFO - PassThroughHttpListener Starting Pass-through HTTP Listener ...
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 28.094] INFO - PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager Pass-through HTTP Listener started on 0.0.0.0:8280
```

We can see that on port 8280 all IPs (0.0.0.0) are bound, instead of 10.10.16.15. We also check the binding with netstat command.

NOTE: We also found  that there was a bug on this configuration item (https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-3117) that should have been solved in ESB version 4.9.0.

The os is Centos 7 with jdk oracle jdk1.7.0_79.

**In the file axis2.xml there is this:**

```
<! - ============================================== === ->
    <! - Transport Ins (Listeners) ->
    <! - ============================================== === ->

     <TransportReceiver name = "http" class = "org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpListener">
        <Parameter name = "port" locked = "false"> 8280 </ parameter>
        <Parameter name = "non-blocking" locked = "false"> false </ parameter>
        <Parameter name = "bind-address" locked = "false"> 10.10.16.15 </ parameter>
        <Parameter name = "WSDLEPRPrefix" locked = "false"> http://10.11.35.10 </ parameter>
        <Parameter name = "httpGetProcessor" locked = "false"> org.wso2.carbon.mediation.transport.handlers.PassThroughNHttpGetProcessor </ parameter>
        <! - <Parameter name = "priorityConfigFile" locked = "false"> location of priority configuration file </ parameter> ->
    </ TransportReceiver>

     <TransportReceiver name = "https" class = "org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLListener">
        <Parameter name = "port" locked = "false"> 8243 </ parameter>
        <Parameter name = "non-blocking" locked = "false"> false </ parameter>
        <Parameter name = "HttpsProtocols"> TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2 </ parameter>
        <Parameter name = "bind-address" locked = "false"> 10.10.16.15 </ parameter>
        <Parameter name = "WSDLEPRPrefix" locked = "false"> https://10.11.35.10 </ parameter>
        <Parameter name = "httpGetProcessor" locked = "false"> org.wso2.carbon.mediation.transport.handlers.PassThroughNHttpGetProcessor </ parameter>
        <Parameter name = "keystore" locked = "false">
```

**My ip on the machine are as follows:**

```
ip addr show
1: I: <LOOPBACK, UP, LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc NOQUEUE been UNKNOWN
    link / loopback 00: 00: 00: 00: 00: 00 brd 00: 00: 00: 00: 00: 00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 brooms host the
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 :: 1/128 brooms host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST, MULTICAST, UP, LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast been UP qlen 1000
    link / ether 52: 54: 00: 3b: 09: 4e brd ff: ff: ff: ff: ff: ff
    inet 10.10.16.15/21 brd 10.10.23.255 brooms global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80 :: 5054: ff: fe3b: 94th / 64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST, MULTICAST, UP, LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast been UP qlen 1000
    link / ether 52: 54: 00: 5b: aa: c8 brd ff: ff: ff: ff: ff: ff
4: eth2: <BROADCAST, MULTICAST, UP, LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast been UP qlen 1000
    link / ether 52: 54: 00: 38: b5: 80 brd ff: ff: ff: ff: ff: ff
    inet 10.11.34.15/24 brd 10.11.34.255 global scope eth2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.11.34.25/24 brd 10.11.34.255 brooms global secondary eth2: 0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80 :: 5054: ff: fe38: B580 / 64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: eth3: <BROADCAST, MULTICAST, UP, LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast been UP qlen 1000
    link / ether 52: 54: 00: e4: 6d: 86 brd ff: ff: ff: ff: ff: ff
    inet 10.11.35.5/24 brd 10.11.35.255 global scope eth3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.11.35.10/24 brd 10.11.35.255 brooms global secondary eth3: 0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80 :: 5054: ff: FEE4: 6d86 / 64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**This is the log:**

```
[Root @ frontend01 ~] # /opt/wso2esb-4.9.0/bin/wso2server.sh
JAVA_HOME environment variable is September to /opt/jdk1.7.0_79/
CARBON_HOME environment variable is September to /opt/wso2esb-4.9.0
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 16.543] INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Starting WSO2 Carbon ...
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 16.546] INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Operating System: Linux 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64, amd64
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 16.546] INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Home: /opt/jdk1.7.0_79/jre
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 16.546] INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Version: 1.7.0_79
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 16.547] INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java VM: Java HotSpot (TM) 64-Bit Server VM 24.79-b02, Oracle Corporation
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 16.547] INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Carbon Home: /opt/wso2esb-4.9.0
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 16.547] INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Temp Dir: /opt/wso2esb-4.9.0/tmp
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 16.547] INFO - CarbonCoreActivator User: root, en-US, Europe / Rome
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 16.637] WARN - SystemValidator Could not validate the system for configuration parameter: CPU
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 16.639] WARN - ValidationResultPrinter Carbon is configured to use the default keystore (wso2carbon.jks). To maximize security When deploying to a production environment, configure a new keystore with a unique password for the production server profile.
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 16.644] INFO - AgentHolder Agent created!
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 16.657] INFO - AgentDS Successfully deployed Agent Client
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 17.949] INFO - EmbeddedRegistryService Configured Registry in 56ms
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 18.012] INFO - RegistryCoreServiceComponent Registry Mode: READ-WRITE
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 19.267] INFO - SolrClient Default Embedded Server Solr Initialized
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 19.455] INFO - UserStoreMgtDSComponent Carbon UserStoreMgtDSComponent activated successfully.
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 23.658] INFO - TaglibUriRule TLD skipped. URI: http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles is already defined
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 24.145] INFO - ClusterBuilder Clustering Has Been disabled
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 24.288] INFO - UserStoreConfigurationDeployer User Store Configuration Deployer initiated.
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 24.289] INFO - UserStoreConfigurationDeployer User Store Configuration Deployer initiated.
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 24.297] INFO - PassThroughHttpSSLSender Initializing Pass-through HTTP / S Sender ...
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 24.308] INFO - ClientConnFactoryBuilder HTTPS Loading Identity Keystore from: repository / resources / security / wso2carbon.jks
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 24.310] INFO - ClientConnFactoryBuilder HTTPS Loading Trust Keystore from: repository / resources / security / client-truststore.jks
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 24.324] INFO - PassThroughHttpSSLSender Pass-through HTTPS Sender started ...
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 24.325] INFO - PassThroughHttpSender Initializing Pass-through HTTP / S Sender ...
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 24.326] INFO - PassThroughHttpSender Pass-through HTTP Sender started ...
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 24.333] INFO - PassThroughHttpSSLListener Initializing Pass-through HTTP / S Listener ...
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 24.353] INFO - PassThroughHttpListener Initializing Pass-through HTTP / S Listener ...
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 24.415] INFO - ModuleDeployer Deploying module: addressing-1.6.1-wso2v14 - file: /opt/wso2esb-4.9.0/repository/deployment/client/modules/addressing-1.6.1 -wso2v14.mar
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 24.418] INFO - ModuleDeployer Deploying module: rampart-1.6.1-wso2v12 - file: /opt/wso2esb-4.9.0/repository/deployment/client/modules/rampart-1.6.1 -wso2v12.mar
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 25.121] WARN - DefaultSchemaGenerator We do not support method overloading. Ignoring [validateAudienceRestriction]
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 25.321] INFO - DeploymentEngine Deploying Web services: org.wso2.carbon.message.processor-4.4.10 -
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 25.331] INFO - DeploymentEngine Deploying Web services: org.wso2.carbon.message.store-4.4.10 -
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 25.842] INFO - DeploymentInterceptor Deploying Axis2 service: wso2carbon STS-super-tenant {}
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 25.864] INFO - DeploymentEngine Deploying Web services: org.wso2.carbon.sts-4.5.6 -
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 25.937] INFO - DeploymentEngine Deploying Web services: org.wso2.carbon.tryit-4.4.7 -
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 26.092] INFO - CarbonServerManager Repository: /opt/wso2esb-4.9.0/repository/deployment/server/
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 26.454] INFO - TenantLoadingConfig tenant Using lazy loading policy ...
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 26.468] INFO - PermissionUpdater Permission Cache updated for tenant -1234
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 26.506] INFO - RuleEngineConfigDS Successfully registered the Rule Config service
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 26.532] INFO - ServiceBusInitializer Starting ESB ...
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 26.552] INFO - ServiceBusInitializer Initializing Apache Synapse ...
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 26.555] INFO - SynapseControllerFactory Using Synapse home: /opt/wso2esb-4.9.0/.
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 26.555] INFO - SynapseControllerFactory Using synapse.xml location: /opt/wso2esb-4.9.0/././repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 26.555] INFO - SynapseControllerFactory Using server name: 10.11.35.10
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 26.558] INFO - SynapseControllerFactory The timeout handler will run every: 15s
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 26.563] INFO - Axis2SynapseController Initializing at Synapse: Wed Jan 20 14:13:26 CET 2016
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 26.568] INFO - CarbonSynapseController Loading the mediation configuration from the file system
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 26.570] INFO - MultiXMLConfigurationBuilder Building synapse configuration from the synapse artifact repository at: ././repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 26.573] INFO - XMLConfigurationBuilder Generating the Synapse configuration model by parsing the XML configuration
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 26.625] INFO - SynapseConfigurationBuilder Loaded Synapse configuration artifact from the repository at: ././repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 26.627] INFO - Axis2SynapseController Loading mediator extensions ...
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 26.635] INFO - DeploymentInterceptor Deploying Axis2 service: echo {super-tenant}
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 26.638] INFO - DeploymentEngine Deploying Web services: Echo.aar - file: /opt/wso2esb-4.9.0/repository/deployment/server/axis2services/Echo.aar
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 26.648] INFO - DeploymentInterceptor Deploying Axis2 service: Version {super-tenant}
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 26.651] INFO - DeploymentEngine Deploying Web services: Version.aar - file: /opt/wso2esb-4.9.0/repository/deployment/server/axis2services/Version.aar
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 26.651] INFO - Axis2SynapseController Deploying the Synapse service ...
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 26.655] INFO - Axis2SynapseController Deploying Proxy services ...
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 26.655] INFO - Axis2SynapseController Deploying EventSources ...
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 26.662] INFO - ServerManager Server ready for processing ...
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 26.705] INFO - MediationStatisticsComponent Statistic Reporter is Disabled
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 26.705] INFO - MediationStatisticsComponent Can not register an observer for mediationStatisticsStore. If you have disabled StatisticsReporter, please enable it in the Carbon.xml
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 28.087] INFO - PassThroughHttpSSLListener Starting Pass-through HTTPS Listener ...
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 28.093] INFO - PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager Pass-through HTTPS Listener started on 0.0.0.0:8243
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 28.093] INFO - PassThroughHttpListener Starting Pass-through HTTP Listener ...
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 28.094] INFO - PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager Pass-through HTTP Listener started on 0.0.0.0:8280
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 28.102] INFO - NioSelectorPool Using a shared selector for servlet write / read
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 28.389] INFO - NioSelectorPool Using a shared selector for servlet write / read
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 28.449] INFO - TaskServiceImpl Task service starting in STANDALONE mode ...
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 28.467] INFO - NTaskTaskManager Initialized task manager. Tenant [-1234]
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 28.484] INFO - RegistryEventingServiceComponent Successfully Initialized on Eventing Registry
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 28.517] INFO - JMXServerManager JMX Service URL: service: jmx: rmi: // localhost: 11111 / jndi / rmi: // localhost: 9999 / jmxrmi
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 28.524] INFO - StartupFinalizerServiceComponent Server: WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus-4.9.0
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 28.525] INFO - StartupFinalizerServiceComponent WSO2 Carbon started in 15 seconds
[01/20/2016 14: 13: 28.688] INFO - CarbonUIServiceComponent Mgt Console URL: https://10.11.35.10:9443/carbon/
```

Comment: We have seen that the problem described in reality not only affects the ports of Synapse 8280 and 8283.

But also the ports of https Administration 9443, tcp 4100 clustering, and those of the servlet http 9764, on all  products IS, AM, ESB.

All these ports are bound to all IP.
So you can not bind the products in question on a single ip

Comment: Same thing happens to wso2ei 6.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that the fix has not gone into WSO2 ESB 4.9.0. It has the Synapse version "2.1.3.wso2v11" and I don't see the code changes in [`PassThroughHttpListener.java`](https://github.com/wso2/wso2-synapse/blob/Apache-Synapse-2.1.3-wso2v11/modules/transports/core/nhttp/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/transport/passthru/PassThroughHttpListener.java). I also don't see any relevant code in the GitHub repository. https://github.com/wso2/wso2-synapse/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=bind-address

I reopened the [ESBJAVA-3117 JIRA](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-3117) and the ESB team will look in to that.

Thanks!

Comment: We have seen that the problem described in reality not only affects the ports of Synapse 8280 and 8283. But also the ports of https Administration 9443, tcp 4100 clustering, and those of the servlet http 9764, on all products IS, AM, ESB. All these ports are bound to all IP. So you can not bind the products in question on a single ip